# Schengen application

Tags: schengen-visas, croatia

I’m planning to travel to France and Croatia and in process of filling in my application form for a Schengen Visa. I believe that I don’t have to apply for a separate visa to Croatia... is that correct?

However, on the drop down box under Other Member Destination State - Croatia is not on the list. How do I answer this question or how do I declare my intention of visiting Croatia using Schengen Visa, please?[image]

Comment: I rolled back the edit as the question is NOT about adding non Schengen travel to a Schengen visa application but about mistakenly thinking the Croatia visa is part of the Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

As you indicate in a comment, you will not need a separate visa for Croatia if your visa meets given requirements.

But the officials who check out your visa application for France will not consider your travel to Croatia as part of your travel plans for this visa.

So you give your details for your travel in the Schengen zone without mentioning Croatia, do mention it in the overall itinerary, where there is place to mention it.

If you do not get a visa that allows you to visit Croatia on your Schengen visa, you will need to apply to a separate Croatia visa.

Comment: there is no place to add a few words like “other information” box. But my visit to Croatia is on my itinerary. Do you think this will do?

Comment: I don't think "without mentioning Croatia" is a good idea. I would expect that the consulate wants a _truthful_ account of the applicants travel plans until they arrive back at their country of residence, at least in broad strokes. Pretending they're going directly home instead of via Croatia would amount to lying in a visa application, wouldn't it?

Comment: I understood your "without mentioning Croatia" as a recommendation to _actively remove mention of Croatia_ from the itinerary they apply with. Once they do that, it is not mentioned anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

Croatia is not in the Schengen area. You need a separate visa for Croatia (unless your citizenship means you don't need a visa for Croatia).

Comment: I believe I don’t need a separate visa as long as my Schengen is dual or multiple entry. http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

Comment: I’m sorry, I will post the question separately. Thanks

Comment: Update: I was granted a multiple entry Schengen visa, hence was able to travel to Croatia as well. As I was traveling to France first, I applied and applied my form via https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/ma-demande-en-ligne , then lodged my applications at VFS Global Manila, the agency responsible for accepting visa applications under the authority of the Embassy of France in Manila (as I am from the Philippines)

Comment: With my printed application form and other supporting documents, my father who is a British citizen wrote a letter for me explaining why I was applying for multiple entry visa and our detailed itinerary. And my application was approved.